# Using BS4 to find specific Options

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How would I use **Beautifulsoup** to find 7 (`<option value="NIC1633_9729">7</option>`)

```
<option value="NIC1633_9729">7</option>
<option value="NIC1633_9730">7 1/8</option>
<option value="NIC1633_9731">7 1/4</option>
<option value="NIC1633_9732">7 3/8</option>
<option value="NIC1633_9733">7 1/2</option>
<option value="NIC1634_9734">7 5/8</option>
<option value="NIC1634_9735">7 3/4</option>
<option value="NIC1634_9736">7 7/8</option>
```

Thanks !

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Please make your question a [mcve]. Also check [ask] to make your post answerable.

Comment: @BibekBhandari yes, been researching all day can't figure it out

Comment: post what you tried, and then i could help

Comment: Also, specify *why* 7 should be the result. It's not clear whether this is because 7 is the first element, 7 is the text for the option with value "NIC1633_9729", 7 is the only whole number in the list, or because 7 is your favorite number.

Comment: 7 should be the result because it's the specific size im looking for on the page. @ReidBallard , very confused on how to pick that specific one

Answer (score 0):

[In the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) under [Searching the Tree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) you can find information on locating elements via various methods. In your case you are looking for an `<option>` element with a text value of `7`. The docs mention that one of the ways you can find elements is by passing a string to `find/findall`. [A little further down](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument), it mentions that you can search for strings using the `string` parameter. So, based on what you've provided:

```
import bs4

html = """
<option value="NIC1633_9729">7</option>
<option value="NIC1633_9730">7 1/8</option>
<option value="NIC1633_9731">7 1/4</option>
<option value="NIC1633_9732">7 3/8</option>
<option value="NIC1633_9733">7 1/2</option>
<option value="NIC1634_9734">7 5/8</option>
<option value="NIC1634_9735">7 3/4</option>
<option value="NIC1634_9736">7 7/8</option>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find("option",string = "7"))
```

The above code returns `<option value="NIC1633_9729">7</option>`.

The section concerning the `string` parameter also mentions that you can use regex (among other possible values) as the argument in case `"7"` is not matching exactly what is on the page that you are working off of.